# Setting NSTableView control Size Programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, xcode13

[image]

If I access the **cell-based** **table view** (`NSTableView`) through the storyboard, I find a property named `controlSize` under the size inspector.  If I select 'large' from the drop-down menu, I will have a large font size in the list.  That's great.  But how do I do it programmatically?  If I try the following, the font size won't change.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

@IBAction func testClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    tableView.rowSizeStyle = .large
    tableView.controlSize = .large
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [NSCell.controlSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscell/1530780-controlsize). "Changing the cell’s control size does not change the font used by the cell.".

Comment: `NSTableView` does not implement `setControlSize:`.

Comment: Take a look at the xib/storyboard as source code, there is no table view control size. IB changes the font of the cells.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks.  It sounds like you are making conflicting statements.  First, you say it won't change the font.  You then say "IB changes the font of the cells."

Comment: Setting `controlSize` programmatically doesn't change the font. Changing "Control Size" in IB changes the font and doesn't set `controlSize`. The cell-based `NSTableView` is deprecated, isn't supported anymore and is getting buggy.